# How to globally set dark mode for GTK-4 apps?

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, gtk, sway, dark-mode

I am trying to set nautilus to dark mode but with no luck.

I tried:

- run this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface color-scheme 'prefer-dark'
```

- setting color scheme in `~/.config/gtk-4.0/gtk.css`

```css
@import url("resource:///org/gtk/libadwaita/ado.css");

AdwStyleContext {
  color-scheme: dark;
}
```

- to set it in `~/.config/gtk-4.0/settings.ini`

```
[Settings]
gtk-enable-animations=true
gtk-icon-theme-name=Adwaita-dark
gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme=0
```

But this has no effect and drops this warning:

```
(org.gnome.Nautilus:69565): Adwaita-WARNING **: 23:24:29.934:
Using GtkSettings:gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme with libadwaita is unsupported.
Please use AdwStyleManager:color-scheme instead.
```

What should I do set globally dark mode for gtk4 apps on my system ?

Additional information: I use Arch linux + wayland + sway
I am using [ly](https://github.com/fairyglade/ly) display manager. I start ly as systemd service:

```
● ly.service - TUI display manager
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/ly.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2024-01-03 10:31:36 CET; 3h 52min ago
   Main PID: 1042 (ly-dm)
      Tasks: 0 (limit: 8734)
     Memory: 2.5M (peak: 5.0M)
        CPU: 39ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/ly.service
             ‣ 1042 /usr/bin/ly-dm
```

Comment: Have you tried `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface color-scheme 'prefer-dark'`? If it works let me know so I can post a complete answer

Comment: When I run this command and start nautilus right after it is still in light mode.

Comment: The gsettings thing does nothing since GTK 4.11.4:
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/commit/15458b5af3343e23f147cb2ace9cd6aa6f7dcffc
The explanation is in the corresponding MR: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/merge_requests/6157

Comment: @JanČerný Please tell me how you start sway (manually from a tty, via a display manager, as a systemd service, etc.) and I will figure something out.

Comment: @selurvedu I added information how I start sway to question itself. If you need more infromation just ask and I will add it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```shell
GTK_THEME=Adwaita-dark
```

to `/etc/environment`.

Comment: In `/etc/environment` you vrite just list `VAR=VAL` without `export` command. I tried it and it works. If you update you answer I will accept it as solution.